# Spark plugs 3 and 5 wearing out faster

Tags: sparkplugs, misfire, chrysler, town-and-country

Two of my spark plugs in my 2013 Town and Country are wearing out much faster than the other four plugs. I have changed the coils for 3 and 5, I have also changed the cam shaft sensor. When those two wear down enough, there is a misfiring. For example, like when I'm going uphill and the engine is needing up upshift it starts misfiring until I press the gas pedal further to force it to upshift. I think I also feel it misfiring when the plugs are new but it's very light.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How do you know it is the sparkplugs? What are you considering "wear" to be on the sparkplugs? What are you using as replacement sparkplugs (OEM or aftermarket)? How many times have you changed them? How are you diagnosing this is actually the issue? Are you getting any trouble codes (CELs)? How do you know it isn't a fueling issue? How many miles are on your van?